# To toggle statusline colors when switching modes. Problem with C-C

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, statusline

I use the following code to have different statusline colors for Normal and Insert modes:

```
                      highlight statusLine  ctermfg=black ctermbg=red    guifg=red   guibg=black
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight statusline  ctermfg=black ctermbg=red    guifg=red   guibg=black
autocmd InsertEnter * highlight statusline  ctermfg=black ctermbg=green  guifg=green guibg=black
```

It works fine for me except the color is not changed back to red when I exit from Insert mode by using `<C-C>`.

Some people suggest to use something like

```
inoremap <c-c> <c-o>:highlight statusline guifg=red guibg=black<cr><c-c>
```

for this, but it doesn't work for me. What's wrong with this line?

Also, why not use just `inoremap <c-c> <Esc>`? It looks much simpler and it works, but I suspect there are some hidden drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine for me except the color is not changed back to red when I exit from Insert mode by using .

If you do `:h i_CTRL-C` you'll get answer on why your statusline is not changed when you hit `<C-c>`:

```
                        *i_CTRL-C*
CTRL-C      Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for
        abbreviations.  Does not trigger the |InsertLeave| autocommand
        event.
```

> Some people suggest to use something like
> `inoremap <c-c> <c-o>:highlight statusline guifg=red guibg=black<cr><c-c>`

If you use terminal without `termguicolors` on, then it wouldn't work for you, because you reset gui colors. Check your original autocommands where you set both term and gui colors. Try maybe

```
inoremap <c-c> <c-o>:highlight statusline ctermfg=black ctermbg=red guifg=red guibg=black<cr><c-c>
```

And it would probably not work because highlighting is applied to statusline in-between insertleave/insertenter (`<C-o>` switches to normal mode for a single command and then goes back to insert mode)

You can try this instead, where highlighting happens after original `<C-c`:

```
inoremap <c-c> <c-c>:highlight statusline guifg=red guibg=black<cr>
```

> Also, why not use just `inoremap <c-c> <Esc>`? It looks much simpler and it works, but I suspect there are some hidden drawbacks.

You can use it if you don't mind loosing original `<C-c>` behavior described in the help above.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, but I use gVim. The current solution doesn't seem to work for it. Even more, the cursor doesn't change from bar to block (weird!)

Comment: @johnc.j. it doesn't work because your highlighting happens in-between 2 autocommands you have defined in the first place. Updated the answer.